# Cannot find mysql bin file in macos

Tags: mysql

I am having a lot of problems with mysql on macos 10.14.  It started with trying to reset my password.  Back when I collaborated with someone in 2018 my collaborator used mysql but I did not know how to work it.  I have a feeling that the password I used for mysql is not the typical password I used because my attempts to log in failed. watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7S_tz1z_5bA) I was told at 9:12 that the password would be set on installation but that turned out to be false.  I was never asked for a password upon downloading but perhaps that is because I had part of mysql already downloaded on my computer but I did not have the workbench installed.  All of my attempts to reset the password failed.  So I then tried deleting mysql and redownloading.  Now I am not able not to start the mysql server from mac's system preferences.  But that's not my largest problem.  I still cannot reset the password and hence even use the app.  Following [official mysql instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) I cannot reset the password because it requires the location of a pid file. It says

> Stop the MySQL server if it is running. Locate the .pid file that contains the server's process ID. The exact location and name of this file depend on your distribution, host name, and configuration. Common locations are /var/lib/mysql/, /var/run/mysqld/, and /usr/local/mysql/data/.

In the folder for mysql located in `/usr/local/var/mysql` there is no pid file. A lot of the tutorials I've seen recommend using terminal but I cannot use terminal for mysql because I get the mysql command not found error.  Ok, so to fix that problem trying this tutorial [here](https://sebhastian.com/mysql-command-not-found/) it says:

> If you’re installing MySQL using the official installer, then your MySQL bin/ folder should be located on /usr/local/bin/mysql

So now I need to find the mysql bin file but when I write `ls` in the `/usr/local/bin` folder, mysql does not come up.  All of the file beginning near 'my' are

```
multinit                
murge                   
nasm
```

So I'm stuck.  I find it simply incredible that such a simple thing as resetting a password is so difficult.

Comment: I decided to get the old folder out of the trash and put it back where it was.  It had a bin folder in it.  Still, I would like to know why installation I performed of mysql had not bin folder

Answer (score -1):

Let’s say we installed MySQL version is 8.0 on our Windows OS. The bin directory is present at the following location −

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin